# SharpDx get Shader variable Names of Texture2D,SamplerState

Tags: c#, directx-11, texture2d, sharpdx, multitexturing

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the Variable names of Texture2D and SamplerState.
I know that I'm able to get those through the effects Framework.
But I'm looking for a way without this Framework. Like the way with Constantbuffers (ShaderReflection).
I want to make the HLSL Code like this

```
   Texture2D tex0;
   Texture2D bg;
```

Does anyone have an idea How I might be able to access the VariableNames without the EffectsFramework?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I'm curious about this too. You might get a response if you ask on the [SharpDX forum](http://sharpdx.org/forum).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok pretty simple here, first compile your shader to get bytecode.

Then create an instance of ShaderReflection

```
byte[] yourbytecode;
SharpDX.D3DCompiler.ShaderReflection sr;
sr = new ShaderReflection(yourbytecode);
```

To find how many resources are bound:

```
int ResourceCount = sr.Description.BoundResources;
```

Then to get details about it:

```
InputBindingDescription desc = sr.GetResourceBindingDescription(index);
```

It contains name, dimension and other usefule data.